# How to change colors in pie charts using canvasxpress

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pie-chart

I have a pie chart with two types of data: ok and not ok. I want to render ok with green and not ok with red. I have searched in the documentation but with no results. So far my code is:

```
new CanvasXpress("orderProgressCanvas", {
  "y": {
    "vars": [
      "Ok",
      "No"
    ],
    "smps": [
      "Percentuale completamento"
    ],
    "colorRGB": [
      "rgb(0,255,0)",
      "rgb(255,0,0)"
    ],
    "data": [
      [
        progress
      ],
      [
        100-progress
      ]
    ]
  }
}, {
  "graphType": "Pie",
  "pieSegmentPrecision": 1,
  "pieSegmentSeparation": 2,
  "pieSegmentLabels": "outside",
  "pieType": "solid",
  "showLegend": false,
  "background" : "rgb(192,208,216)"
});
```

But color definition doesn't work.. any idea?
progress is a javascript variable from 0 to 100.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked to the main developer:

> Just put the colors you want in the colors property in the
>   configuration. They will be selected in the order you specify them.
>   Also make sure you specify enough colorr otherwise they will be
>   recycled as they are used.

```
'colors': ['rgb(234,234,1)', 'rgb(56,35,12)'.......etc]
```

My code has become:

```
new CanvasXpress("orderProgressCanvas", {
  "y": {
    "vars": [
      "Ok",
      "No"
    ],
    "smps": [
      "Percentuale completamento"
    ],
    "data": [
      [
        progress
      ],
      [
        100-progress
      ]
    ],
  }
}, {
  "graphType": "Pie",
  "pieSegmentPrecision": 1,
  "pieSegmentSeparation": 2,
  "pieSegmentLabels": "outside",
  "pieType": "solid",
  "showLegend": false,
  "background" : "rgb(192,208,216)",
  "colors": [
           "rgb(57,133,0)",
           "rgb(163,0,8)"
           ],
});
```